# Android listview / UI get stuck when adding new item into listview

Tags: android, performance, listview

I am using listview inside scrollview which add new item when listview reached bottom. All is working perfectly but at the time of adding / getting new items from server (before showing those in list) app is getting truck for a while.
I am using AsyncHttpClient library for getting data from server.

I am setting adapter like,

```
if(adapter == null) {
                adapter = new NetworkAdapter(activity, fragmentManager, R.layout.lv_network_custom_row, networkDataArrayList);
                lvNetwork.setAdapter(adapter);
                Log.d("network_response","adapter set");
            }
            else {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.d("network_response","adapter notify");
            }
```

As far as I understand I am creating adapter object single time and later just notifying changes.
Also I am retaining its previous position by,

```
int index = lvNetwork.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            View v = lvNetwork.getChildAt(0);
            int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();
lvNetwork.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
```

I also need to set listview height dynamically and I am doing this by,

```
ListAdapter myListAdapter = listView.getAdapter();

    if (myListAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int size = 0; size < myListAdapter.getCount(); size++) {

        View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, listView);
        if (listItem instanceof ViewGroup)
            listItem.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        int screenWidth = display.getWidth();
        int listViewWidth = screenWidth - 65;
        int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listViewWidth,
                View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        listItem.measure(widthSpec, 0);

        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

        listTotalHeight = totalHeight;
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (myListAdapter.getCount()));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
```

I have debugged code and I guess stuck occurred while setting listview height.

What I want is, app / UI would not get stuck before showing newly added item. How can I solve this?
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: you didn't show how you add data to adapter

Comment: for whats worth, move these out of the for loop

from: 
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
to:
        int listViewWidth = screenWidth - 65;